# Getting "Loading Botium plugin from directline3" even after installing directline3

Tags: direct-line-botframework

I followed the steps at https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-connector-directline3

```
> npm install -g botium-cli
> npm install -g botium-connector-directline3
> botium-cli init
> botium-cli run
```

But, running
`botium-cli run --config path/to/botium.json --convos give_me_a_picture.convo.txt` gives me this

```
Error: Loading Botium Plugin failed.
Loading Botium plugin from directline3 failed - Cannot find module 'directline3'
Loading Botium plugin botium-connector-directline3 failed, try "npm install botium-connector-directline3" - Cannot find module 'botium-core'
at tryLoadPlugin (/Users/<user>/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/lib/node_modules/botium-cli/node_modules/botium-core/src/containers/plugins/index.js:133:9)
      at PluginConnectorContainer.Validate (/Users/<user>/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/lib/node_modules/botium-cli/node_modules/botium-core/src/containers/PluginConnectorContainer.js:14:27)
```

Is this an issue with the node version 10.13.0 that I have?
My botium.json

```
  "botium": {
    "Capabilities": {
      "PROJECTNAME": "My Botium Project",
      "CONTAINERMODE": "directline3",
      "DIRECTLINE3_SECRET": "<secret>",
      "DIRECTLINE3_WEBSOCKET": true,
      "DIRECTLINE3_POLLINGINTERVAL": 1000
    },
    "Sources": {},
    "Envs": {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue got resolved after I ran `npm install -g botium-core`